# Where to store counter for another table's column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, schema

I have a database requirement that is a slight twist on the standard invoicing system you'd see in most DB introductions. My invoicing system has multiple "offices" that are unrelated. Therefore, respective invoice numbers are different per-office. The actual invoice number is obviously different than the primary key.

For example, Offices A and B could both have different invoice #1005.

Is there a best practice to storing a counter for another table?

```
create table Offices (
    Id integer primary key,
    InvoiceCounter integer not null,
    Name varchar(32) not null
);

create table Invoices (
    Id int primary key,
    InvoiceNumber int not null,
    Comment varchar(512) not null
    -- other columns...
);
```

This is the algorithm that I thought of when creating a new invoice:

1. Get the current InvoiceCounter for the Office.
2. Increment by one and insert with the invoice.
3. Update the Office with the new InvoiceCounter number.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Is reusing #1005 at multiple Offices a requirement?  Why not just put Office.Id in the Invoice table and rely on an identity column on Invoice table?

Comment: @NathanSkerl - I should have mentioned that there is also an import from an existing database from each office. Invoices are obviously printed and therefore the reference to 1005 in A needs to be intact if a customer calls up about their printed invoice with # 1005.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you need to concern yourself with is the potential for race conditions since. E.g. to people try to get the next Inv# and they both get 1006 back.

To avoid this use [sp_getapplock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx) to block while you're calculating the next number

The reason why this is a good idea is because Transactions don't typically block reads. e.g. T1 reads 1005 but before it writes 1006, T2 also reads 1005. When T1 finishes the transaction T2 goes ahead and also write 1006. This will cause your transaction to fail if your unique key is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to try not to explicitly block if you can.  Only do that as a last resort. Can't you just retry the transaction if a transaction fails due to two transactions for the same office pulling the same invoice number? The failing transaction just needs to retry getting the next available invoice number for the given office.

This does assume you have a unique key which contains the office# and invoice#.